# Rails current_user nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller, in this controller @current user is OK in show, new, create, but doesn't work in def _params, for example, @current_user.role:
undefined method `role' for nil:NilClass.
Thanks.

```
def company_params
  if @current_user.role.name != 'admin'
    params[:company_id] = @current_user.company.id
  end
  params.require(:company).permit(.........)
end
```

ERROR: undefined method `role' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Would you mind showing this controller's code?

Comment: Please include more information. See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Also consider taking the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Where is `@current_user` defined? Are you using Devise?

Answer (score 0):

`@current_user` is defined in a filter at the begginng but just for the defined actions. The company params doesn't seem to be included in the list. Try adding it.

```
before_action :set_current_user, only: [:balbalba, :company_params] #might look different
```